# Specflow - Step argument transformation - Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, bdd, specflow

I am struggling with Step argument transformation.
Basically what I want to do is to transform every step which has 
'... category page' text inside to the CategoryPage object

Feature file step looks like this

```
I have this step in feature file:
    Given a webrowser is at "Women's dresses category page"
```

a method in Step definitions class looks like this :

```
 [Given(@"a webrowser is at ""(.* category page)""")]
        public void GivenAWebrowserIsAt(CategoryPage p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0.Title);
        }
```

and my argument Transformation class looks like this

```
namespace merino_bdd_test.Transformers
{
    [Binding]
    public class CategoryPageTransformer
    {
        [StepArgumentTransformation(@"(.* category page""")]
        public CategoryPage TransformIntoCategoryOage(string categoyPage)
        {                     

            return new CategoryPage(categoyPage, categoyPage);
        }
    }
}
```

CategoryPage class to which I want to transform step looks like this

```
namespace merino_bdd_test.Utils
{
    public class CategoryPage
    {
        public string Title {get;set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }

        public CategoryPage(string title, string link)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Link = link;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting **Message: System.InvalidCastException : Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'merino_bdd_test.Utils.CategoryPage'.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Once, you have specified the transformation, you do not need to specify the the argument in the `Given` again.
Refer this [link](https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/03/improve-your-specflow-scenarios-with-custom-step-argument-transformations/)

I have not tested this, but try modifying your `Given` code as below:

```
[Given(@"a webrowser is at (.*)")]
public void GivenAWebrowserIsAt(CategoryPage p0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p0.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have left a `"` inside the regex of the step argument transformation.
The correct attribute should be:

```
[StepArgumentTransformation(@"(.* category page)"]
```